# Programmatically swipe Android view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-canvas, android-recyclerview

## What I need:

I have a recyclerview, what I want to do is to for example (pseucode at end):

1. Get first item view (`myView`)
2. Swipe `myView` to left 100px - `myView.Swipe(translationX, -100px)`
3. Swipe `myView` back to original position `myView.Swipe(translationX, 0px)`

Is there anyway to do this?

**Important** I want to emulate the swiping (as if user was swiping over view) not animate the translationX. I already have my code of what view does onSwipe but I want to give user hint of what happens when user swipes to left.

This is what happens on swiping:

1. Original state:

[image]

2. User swipes to left:

[image]

[image]

## My problem:

When using animation pink canvas with trash icon does NOT appear. So I need to emulate/simulate the swiping action.

## Update:

I'm using android native ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback to listen for swipe and onChildDraw() to draw pink canvas when RecyclerView items are swiped.

Comment: are you using a library to swipe?

Comment: you can check this tutorial on how its done -- http://www.jayrambhia.com/blog/swipe-listview/

Comment: @Mo1989, I'm using android native ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback to listen for swipe and onChildDraw() to draw pink canvas when RecyclerView items are swiped.

Comment: consider using this https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout

Comment: consider to use that library https://github.com/xenione/SwipeLayout. You can even custom your own swipe out effects

Comment: Did you ever find a way to implement this?

Comment: any solution found?